# Centos 7 to Automatically connect to a Bluetooth device when it's available

Tags: centos, bluetooth, scanner

I need to connect Zebra ring scanners to Cent OS boxes. With Bluetoothctl I am able to connect to one with a specific BT address, however our users in the workhouse are using an application which launches right after the system boots up and have no access to any shell whatsoever. My question would be is there a way to make Bluetoothctl scan for specific Bluetooth devices and automatically connect to them when it finds one it trusts. Example scenario would be 2 scanners/pc, if ones battery dies it connects to the other one or if the system reboots it would start to scan for the dedicated devices in the backround and connect to them right away as one is available. Thanks for any reply in advance!